# Как реализовать коннект любого поддомена в папку www домена?

Tags: php, .htaccess

Необходимо при запросах к поддоменам:

111.site.ru

222.site.ru

volga.site.ru и т.д.,

переадресовывать запрос в папку /subdomain/ - www домена, чтобы скрипты расположенные там выполняли задуманные функции.

Как реализовать коннект поддоменов в папку www домена, чтобы адрес поддомена, оставался поддоменом, сохранялся в виде поддомена - 111.site.org но подтягивал файлы из site.org/subdomain/ ?

`Запись *.site.ru настроена.`

Мой .htaccess основного домена

```
DirectoryIndex index.php

AddDefaultCharset UTF-8

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%1/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|cron\.php|update\.php|robots\.txt|assets|images|js|css|uploads|subdomains|favicon.png)
RewriteCond %(REQUEST_FILENAME) !-f
RewriteCond %(REQUEST_FILENAME) !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ./index.php?/$1 [L]
</IfModule>`
```

.htaccess в папке subdomains

`RewriteEngine off`

Сейчас при обращении к subdomains.site.org все работает корректно, при обращении к любому другому поддомену - 500 ошибка.

Спасибо!

Answer (score 2):

Для каждого поддомена создать свой виртуальный хост в конфиге Апача, где DocumentRoot будет нужная Вам папка

Comment: Поддомены создаются автоматически, по факту их нет, все поддомены должен обрабатывать 1 файл из папки /subdomain/ - www домена

Answer (score 1):

Если вам нужно прокидывать запрос думаю должен помочь [symlink](http://linux-notes.org/sozdanie-ssy-lok-symlink-v-unix-linux/)

Comment: Похоже на symlink, но как реализовать не понял. Сейчас при обращении к поддомену появляется ошибка 500 - Internal Server Error В isp настроено автоподдомены внутри www домена https://i.gyazo.com/f57fafa935ff24317102985d2476ae27.png

Comment: Смотрите, вам нужно в корневой папке домена сделать симлинк вместо www. (если у вас www корневая директория домена). Т.е. что то вроде
ln -s {/www/subdomain} {www}

Comment: Внес правки в вопрос, похоже у меня проблемы с самим .htaccess

Comment: Выполнил 2 команды `ln -s site.org /var/www/ivan/data/www/site.org/subdomains
ln -s . /var/www/ivan/data/www/site.org` создался файл в папке subdomains - site.org После ввода второй команды, получил сообщение File exists. Поддомены не заработали.